# How to check every record in relative table in sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, join, pdo

I am struggling with one query.

I have three tables 
deviations : Can have more than one measures
measure_sources : relation table of deviation and measure
measures

Here I want to check this on every measure related to deviation
due_at > currentdate : should visible
due_at < currentdate : not shown

Deviation Table

```
id name
1   abc
2   def
```

measure sources table

```
id  element_id measure_id
1      1        1
2      1        2
3      1        3
4      2        1
5      2        2
```

measures table

```
id  due_at
1    2015-10-14
2    2015-12-30
3    2016-11-30
```

expected result

```
id 
2
```

Currently I am using below query but I am getting the deviation that should not be come

```
SELECT  d.id FROM deviations d 
LEFT JOIN measure_sources ms ON ms.element_id = d.id 
LEFT JOIN measures m ON ms.measure_id = m.id 
WHERE (m.due_at > '2016-08-15' OR m.due_at is null)
```

But currently I am getting 1 and 2 both as result 
please suggest where I am wrong

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Kindly provide your sample data. Please

Comment: Since you do not provide us with usefull information we can only guess. For instance, you join table Devations with Measure_sources and the key in table measure_sources you join on is called element_id. Are you sure that is correct ? I would expect a field called deviationID in table measure_sources to join these tables with

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your problem is.  However, I can see a big potential problem with the query.  In general, when using `left join`, conditions on all but the first table should be in the `on` clause.

Perhaps this will fix your problem:

```
SELECT d.id
FROM deviations d LEFT JOIN
     measure_sources ms
     ON ms.element_id = d.id LEFT JOIN
     measures m
     ON ms.measure_id = m.id AND
        m.due_at > '2016-08-15' ;
```

Comment: No I am still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `LEFT JOIN`s, but `INNER` (plus `DISTINCT`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.id FROM deviations d 
JOIN measure_sources ms
  ON ms.element_id = d.id 
JOIN measures m
  ON ms.measure_id = m.id 
WHERE m.due_at > '2016-08-15'
```

And if you don't need additional columns from `deviations` you can remove a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ms.element_id 
FROM measure_sources ms
JOIN measures m
  ON ms.measure_id = m.id 
WHERE m.due_at > '2016-08-15'
```

Comment: I need deviation and I have tried with Inner join but now I get only id 1 as result :(

Comment: @user3198315: 1 is the only `element_id` where a `due_at` > current date exists, this matches your (a bit confusing) description. Mayby you want the `element_id` where *all* rows have a `due_at` < current date? You probably need to add more details to your question, why or why not a row is included in the result.